# No component found for view with name "ARTShape"

Tags: react-native

Just trying to produce an hello-world for using the ART object in React Native, I get the above exception as if part of the library were not linked. I just added the following code:

```
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ART
 } from 'react-native';
```

...

    `<Text style={styles.instructions}>
       Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
       Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
     </Text>
     <ART.Shape
       fill={"black"}
       d={"M10,10 L 30,30"}/>
    </View>`
...

to `index.ios.js` after `react-native init my-app`. So what am I doing wrong? Do I have to link some package with `rnpm`?

react-native-cli: 0.2.0
react-native: 0.27.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get all your `ART` components wrapped with the `Surface` element.

```
const { Surface, Shape } = ART;
```

...

```
<Surface width={ 100 } height={100}>
  <Shape></Shape>
</Surface>
```

Comment: I see. Now to exception turned into 'No component found for view with name “ARTSurfaceView”', so it's still not working (the same on rnplay.org, by the way). How did you find this information? Is there some docs I missed?

Comment: @StefanoPugnetti you have to link [ART.xcodeproj](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/ART) to your project,because unlike View or Text module it haven't been linkded by default.There's no documentation with this but you can easily solve it by google the error message.Good luck.

Comment: I was not aware of ART being a [Library](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html), and googling the Exception I did not find [this good beginner's guide](http://browniefed.com/blog/getting-react-art-running-on-react-native/). Now I can display my graphics. By the way, the visible prop doesn't seem necessary for me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @StefanoPugnetti Congratulations! it seems that the `visible` is not a necessary property ( default is true ) ,I'll update my answer,thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 48):

You need to link the ART Library to your iOS project.

Refer to [the React Native document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#manual-linking),

1. Find the ART Xcode Project in the node_module/react-native

[image]

---

2. Drag the ART Project into your project_folder/Libraries

[image]

---

3. Go the Build Phase tab of YOUR PROJECT, add libART.a into Link Binary into Libraries.

[image]

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: As of June 2018 linking binary with libaries will break your project if it is an xcode project and not a workspace (currently testing to confirm and give more details...)

Comment: Seems fine in July 2018

Comment: it was hard for me, because i was using the xcode for the first time, so please can you make this more detailed ....

Comment: in my case, follow this answer, then when xcode restart, problem solved.

Answer (score 19):

There is no ART.xcodeproject it RN> 0.61. In /ios/Podfile add

```
pod 'React-ART', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART'
```

Comment: Why is this answer criminally downvoted while being the most up-to-date one? It solved the error on react-native@0.61.2

Comment:  This worked after I deleted the ios/build, restarted the bundler and the simulator. — For newer RN devs, don't forget to run pod install after updating the Podfile.

Comment: this helped a lot. the project has shown a result!)

also it began to install 3 pods, not just ART:
`➜  ios pod install
Detected React Native module pod for RNSVG
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing RNSVG (9.13.6)
Installing React-ART (0.61.5)
Installing React-Core 0.61.5`

Answer (score 5):

I drag and dropped node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART/ART.xcodeproj somewhere to my Xcode project. After that I was able to add libART.a under Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

source:
https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-progress/issues/23

Answer (score 1):

> For react native >= 0.60 for ARTShape component not found issue:

Open Podfile and add below given path and save the file

> pod 'React-ART', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART'

From your root folder navigate to ios folder of the app:

> cd ios

now inside ios folder

> pod install

Close existing metro bundler ,close Xcode.

> open Xcode > clean build folder and Build.
>   This works for me !!!