# Unable to build React Native project on iOS: No component found for view with name "ARTShape"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I receive the following error when I try building a React Native app on iOS:

```
No component found for view with name "ARTShape"
```

I don't have any such problems on Android. I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49381982/4077294) but it's not working: in Xcode, after making those changes and pressing CMD+B, I am receiving the following error under the category `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue`:

```
'React/UIView+React.h': file not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Use POD linking `ART` library like this:

1) Add ART to pod file

`pod 'React-ART', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART'`

2) run `pod update` to ios directory.